# How to read struct field ` ` decorators?

Tags: json, struct, go, unmarshalling

My package needs to be able to let my users define the fields backend database column name explicitly, if they want to.

By default I will use the fields name - but sometimes they will need to manually specify the column name, just like the JSON package - unmarshal uses the explicit name if required.

How can I consume this explicit value in my code? I don't even know what it's called so Google is really failing me at the moment.

Here's what JSON's unmarshal function needs for example:

```
type User struct {
    Name string
    LastName    string  `json:"last_name"`
    CategoryId  int     `json:"category_id"`
}
```

What would I need to use something like this?

```
// Paprika is my package name.
type User struct {
    Name string
    LastName    string   `paprika:"last_name"`
    CategoryId  int      `paprika:"category_id"`
}
```

My package will be constructing SQL queries and I can't just rely on the field's name - I need to be able to let them manually set the column name. So this is working with only the defined columns at the moment.

```
// Extracts resource information using reflection and
// saves field names and types.
func loadTypeToSchema(resource interface{}) {
    resourceType := reflect.TypeOf(resource)

    // Grab the resource struct Name.
    fullName := resourceType.String()
    name := fullName[strings.Index(fullName, ".")+1:]

    // Grabs the resource struct fields and types.
    fieldCount := resourceType.NumField()
    fields := make(map[string]string)
    for i := 0; i <= fieldCount-1; i++ {
        field := resourceType.Field(i)
        fields[field.Name] = field.Type.Name()
    }

    // Add resource information to schema map.
    schema[name] = fields
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, what you call decorators are actually called [tags](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Tag). You can read these tags using reflection. The `reflect` package even has its [own example](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#example_StructTag) for that.

Nevertheless, here's another example that prints all tags of the members of a struct ([Click to play](http://play.golang.org/p/G--ljQ06Iu)):

```
type Foo struct {
    A int `tag for A`
    B int `tag for B`
    C int
}

func main() {
    f := Foo{}
    t := reflect.TypeOf(f)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(t.Field(i).Tag)
    }
}
```

Note that in case `f` is a pointer, e.g. a `*Foo`, you'd have to indirect (dereference) that value first or else the type returned by `TypeOf` is not a struct but a pointer and `NumField` as well as `Field()` would not work.

Comment: Much obliged - now I know what to call em!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what indirect or dereference is?

Comment: @Serg Well, dereferencing of a pointer is getting the value it points to. If `f` is of type `*Foo`, then `*f` returns the value `f` points to. The way to do this with reflection is using the [`Indirect()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect) method on the reflected value.

Comment: Appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Also useful is the `Get(key)` method on `StructField.Tag`: it lets you look up the prefixed keys in the field tag such that you can interoperate with other users of the tag.