# How to detect if received JSON has unknown fields

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to find some way to prohibit arbitrary JSON keys and fields in Go. For now, if I send payload with undeclared fields in struct, the service will work normally and will map the entity described fields (like`json:"id,omitempty"`).
For example:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar         int        `json:"id,omitempty"`
}
```

Received JSON:

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "hey": "hey"
}
```

Can anybody help me to find the way of tracking unknown field in payload? I need to return an error in that case.

Comment: So you are saying you want to throw an error when fields like ```"hey"``` in your example are sent as part of the payload?

Comment: @kkaosninja, yes

Comment: FYI while in java we "throw" errors, in golang we just "return" them :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update:

you might want to use [`DisallowUnknownFields()` read for more info](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields)

---

### old answer:

There is a proposal for golang 1.9 on this: [proposal: some way to reject unknown fields in encoding/json.Decoder](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15314)

Till then you could try something like this [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ia_zOMdlXT) (code also below).
The key idea is to parse the json into a map[string]interface{} and then work with the keys. This will of course get much more complicated if you have nested structs.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    Bar int `json:"id,omitempty"`
}
var allowedFooKeys = []string{"id"}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`{
      "id": 12,
      "hey": "hey"
    }`)
    m := map[string]interface{}{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for k, _ := range m {
        if !keyExists(k, allowedFooKeys) {
            fmt.Println("Disallowed key in JSON:", k)
        }
    }
}

func keyExists(key string, keys []string) bool {
    for _, k := range keys {
        if k == key {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

You can even get rid of the variable `allowedFooKeys` by getting the allowed keys directly from the `Foo` struct using reflect. For more info on that see here: [How to read struct field ` ` decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840362/how-to-read-struct-field-decorators)

Answer (score 1):

Since Go 1.10, the JSON decoder provides the `DisallowUnknownFields()` option for this use case.

```
func StrictUnmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(data))
    dec.DisallowUnknownFields()
    return dec.Decode(v)
}
```

You can find a full working example here:

https://go.dev/play/p/HoGDIt8nJB7

Comment: Be careful that the code above does not fail if there is junk after a JSON. See [here for more information](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36225#issuecomment-1649618098).